# jquery null value checking methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

Among the following two code, which is the best method to check a null item in jquery. What are the differences? or can you suggest any other best method?.

```
if(!$('#id').val()){
  //code
}
```

or

```
if($('#id').val()==''){
  //code
}
```

Comment: I guess `!$(...).val().trim()`

Comment: The first one, by the way the second one is unsafe equality, === is better

Comment: but what is wrong with my question? Getting few down votes?

Comment: Already answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`""` is by default a falsy value, and `.val()` if element exists and the value is blank will return `""`

`!""` will equate to true so your first approach should be just fine.

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

I think this below method is best

```
if($('#id').val()==''){
  //code
}
```

And Also Try this also

```
if($('#id').val().length == 0){
      //code
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain your choice ?

Comment: First One is best